# EntityFramework Business Logic on EntitySetReference

Tags: entity-framework, business-logic

I am trying to do something where if have a two classes (that i care about)  one called Inquiries and the other is a foreign Key Table of InquiryStatus

What my business logic I  am trying to check if the Inquiry gets tied to a new InquiryStatus which would have InquiryStatus.bln_requiresValue then I need to have an Inquiry.Money

Right now i have

> ```
> public partial class Inquiry
> {
>     partial void OnInquiryIdChanging(int value)
>     {
>         if (EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Added)
>         {
>               var Ekey = InquiryStatusReference.Value;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

But Ekey is always null so is InquiryStatusReference.EntityKey

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **InquiryStatusReference.Load()** before assigning Ekey?